# Complex program escaping

Tags: python, bash, postgresql, fabric

I have a fabfile that I would like to run a command to create a postgres database.

The SQL request is:

```
CREATE DATABASE "dbname"
WITH ENCODING = 'UTF8'
     LC_COLLATE = 'en_US.UTF8'
     LC_CTYPE = 'en_US.UTF8'
     TEMPLATE = template0 
     OWNER = "dbowner";
```

I want to run it using:

```
from fabric.api import run
run("""sudo su postgres --command "psql -c 'REQUEST HERE'" """)
```

But I couldn't find any way of escaping it the right way.

Do you have any idea of how I could do it?

Comment: http://www.sqlalchemy.org/

Comment: Can't you save SQL into a file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I finally did it like that:

```
run('sudo su postgres --command \'psql -e -c "CREATE DATABASE peopleask WITH ENCODING = \'"\'"\'UTF8\'"\'"\' LC_COLLATE = \'"\'"\'en_US.UTF8\'"\'"\' LC_CTYPE = \'"\'"\'en_US.UTF8\'"\'"\' TEMPLATE = template0 OWNER = peopleask;"\'')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `\` to escape double quotes with in a double quoted string and like wise for single quotes with in a single quoted string.

Comment: First step I can do that : `psql -c "CREATE DATABASE dbname WITH ENCODING = 'UTF8' LC_COLLATE = 'en_US.UTF8' LC_CTYPE = 'en_US.UTF8' TEMPLATE = template0 OWNER = dbowner;"`

Comment: Then I can do that: `sudo su postgres --command "psql -e -c \"CREATE DATABASE dbname WITH ENCODING = 'UTF8' LC_COLLATE = 'en_US.UTF8' LC_CTYPE = 'en_US.UTF8' TEMPLATE = template0 OWNER = dbowner;\""`

Comment: Then I can't figure out how to go futher: This doesn't work: `run("""sudo su postgres --command "psql -e -c \\"CREATE DATABASE dbname WITH ENCODING = 'UTF8' LC_COLLATE = 'en_US.UTF8' LC_CTYPE = 'en_US.UTF8' TEMPLATE = template0 OWNER = dbowner;\\"" """)`

Comment: And moreover this doesn't work either: run("""sudo su postgres --command "psql -e -c \\\"CREATE DATABASE dbname WITH ENCODING = 'UTF8' LC_COLLATE = 'en_US.UTF8' LC_CTYPE = 'en_US.UTF8' TEMPLATE = template0 OWNER = dbowner;\\\"" """)